# How can be loading spinner implemented in angular 2 application when there is delay in response for http requests?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, loading

How can be "loading spinner" implemented in angular 2 application when there is delay in response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it. I'll mention two ways:

Lets say, the value of property prop depends on some external sources (ie http calls ) and then in your template you can do the following:

```
  <ng-template *ngIf="prop else loading">
         {{prop}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #loading>
    <div class="ajax-loader">
         <img src="/assets/ajax-loading-img.gif" >
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Another way could be:

```
  export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
     isLoading = false;

    ngOnInit(){
       this.isLoading = true;
       this.http.get(this.apiendpoint)
           .do(()=> { // normal case scenario
               this.isLoading = false;
           }, ()=> { // error case scenario
               this.isLoading = false;
           })
           .subscribe( (data) => {
              // do your operation here. 

           });
    }
  }
```

In the template:

```
  <ng-template *ngIf="isLoading">
    <div class="ajax-loader">
         <img src="/assets/ajax-loading-img.gif" >
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: I would suggest `this.http.get(...).do(_ => this.isLoading = false).subscribe()`.

This way the loading is toggled in a separate step in a `do` handler, instead of two identical lines in `subscribe` handlers.

Comment: How about using an npm package angular2-busy?

Comment: @asmmahmud Thanks for the solution .

Comment: But, before using any angular npm package, make it sure that it is regularly updated. Because, Angular api is still updating pretty fast.

Comment: I used Angular 2 Busy package for loading spinner .It worked for me. Reference --https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

Comment: If so, then wouldn't it be great if you appreciate my answer with a up vote. ( a little encouragement).

Comment: Have one from me instead